# Wake from sleep listener

Tags: android, oauth, sleep, wakelock

I want to call a method in my app when the android device wakes from sleep.

Here's the whole issue:

1. I need to refresh the access-token every 30 minutes. So, if the device is not sleeping, and the app is open (be it in the background or foreground), I will call the refresh-token method every 30 minutes.
2. But when the device goes to sleep, the refresh-token method doesn't get called.
3. So, when the phone wakes after some time (>30 minutes) and the user tries a network request, that would go unauthorized and the user will have to login again.
4. Since I don't want the users to login again, I want to apply for the refresh-token as soon as the device wakes up from the sleep mode.

Therefore, I want to call the refresh-token method in the listener to the wake in my app. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` with `IntentFilter` for `PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED` and then you can check if you are in sleep mode using the `PowerManager.isDeviceIdleMode` and also don't forget to check if your app is in the whitelist with `PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(Context)`.

Alternatively, you can set a periodic task with:

- [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager)
- [JobScheduler (API 21+)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)